# list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, errors

I have problem running my thesis document. I receive the following error if I activate my `\listoffigures` command.

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.59 ...ved@d = *\def {\@@par }}}{86}{figure.5.12}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
Underfull \hbox (badness 4765) in paragraph at lines 59--59
\T1/pplx/m/n/10.95 com-pared to that of bulk stan-dards. A k-window of 4.4-12.
5
[]
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.59 ...ved@d = *\def {\@@par }}}{86}{figure.5.12}
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
! pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode.
\close@pdflink ...\Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink
l.59 ...ved@d = *\def {\@@par }}}{86}{figure.5.12}
```

and while I deactivated the command the program run.

Comment: You need to show a MWE, I think.

Comment: Welcome! We need a small, complete document which we can compile to reproduce the error. You may have a `\\ ` somewhere you shouldn't.

Comment: It should be mentioned that some captions get messed up when written to the lof file.  You may need to use a simpler version in the optional [short caption] argument.

Comment: Deleting the `.aux` and `.lof` files and recompilation can help too

Comment: Is there any news here?